# Keeping the last entry but removing other duplicate row(s) in a data frame using R

Tags: r

I have a large table containing thousands of entries queried from a database having a structure similar to that in Table 1 in the image below. I would like to keep the duplicate row that has the highest value for Var 1, as shown in Table 2. The situation is similar to that is described in an earlier query in this forum [remove duplicates based on one column and keep last entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286284/remove-duplicates-based-on-one-column-and-keep-last-entry). Selecting the rows by using a simple `for` loop works but, it is taking a long time to run. Is there a faster elegant way of handling this in R?

```
Table1 <- structure(list(Var1 = 1001:1009, Var2 = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", 
"AAA", "DDD", "BBB", "AAA", "EEE", "DDD"), Var3 = c(95L, 100L, 
90L, 95L, 85L, 100L, 95L, 45L, 85L), Var4 = c("mg", "kg", "pg", 
"mg", "mg", "kg", "mg", "mg", "mg")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", 
"Var3", "Var4"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(Var1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Var2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Var3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Var4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4")), 
    default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` after grouping by 'Var2'

```
library(dplyr)
Table1 %>%
    group_by(Var2) %>%
    slice(which.max(Var1)) %>%
    arrange(Var1)
#     Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4    
#     <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
#  1  1003   CCC    90    pg 
#  2  1006   BBB   100    kg
#  3  1007   AAA    95    mg
#  4  1008   EEE    45    mg
#  5  1009   DDD    85    mg
```

---

Or do an `arrange` and then `filter` the non-duplicates

```
Table1 %>% 
     arrange(Var2, -Var1) %>% 
     filter(!duplicated(Var2)) %>%
     arrange(Var1)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Table1)[order(Var2,-Var1)][!duplicated(Var2)][order(Var1)]
```

NOTE: This can be done within one step using `fromLast=TRUE` with `duplicated`, but here we are not sure whether the values are already ordered or not in the original dataset.  So, compact method doesn't mean that it works always

We can also use a compact code

```
Table1[c(3, 6:9),]
```

as another way to get the expected :-)

Answer (score 4):

`duplicated` have a `fromLast` option!

```
Table1[!duplicated(Table1$Var2, fromLast = T), ]
```

It should be noted that we have to sort by `Var1` first if the data are not already ordered by `Var1`.

Comment: @MikeH. Sure. you comment comes When I am editing to note about this.

Comment: Very elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `ave` to perform a group operation. Here a logical vector is returned which indicates if the observation is equal to the maximum value of Var1. This is used to subset.

```
Table1[as.logical(ave(Table1$Var1, Table1$Var2, FUN=function(i) i == max(i))),]
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
3 1003  CCC   90   pg
6 1006  BBB  100   kg
7 1007  AAA   95   mg
8 1008  EEE   45   mg
9 1009  DDD   85   mg
```

Comment: Your answer gave me ideas on how to solve this and other issues that I am trying to fix.